# Redirect from lightning page to record page on classic

Tags: lightning, redirect, classic

I'm trying to redirect from a lightning custom page to a record page in classic.
I tried this

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
    "recordId": caseId,
    "slideDevName": "related"
});
navEvt.fire();
```

And this

```
var eUrl= $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
eUrl.setParams({
    "url": '/'+ caseId
});
eUrl.fire();
```

But I'm always getting the lightning version.

Comment: Because both the events you have mentioned will be fired in the context of Lightning Experience, you won't be redirected to Classic

Answer (score 0):

The events you have mentioned here, are both handled by the `one.app` container.

- [force:navigateToSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation)
- [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation)

If you refer to the documentation of these events, you will find the below statement.

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

I am not sure what is your use case of navigating to the "Classic record details" from LEX but using these events will necessarily means that any redirect to records will be always within that experience.

Also take a look at this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_vf_concepts/units/lex_dev_lc_vf_concepts_architecture) to get some more details on this.

Comment: I would imagine due to him working with cases would likely be to enable the case comment functionality as this currently doesn't work in lighting.